# sys_ext form exclude some fields from receiver email

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I use TYPO3 9 LTS, sysext form. In the receiver e-mail are all fields of the form included. Some of the fields are not necessary - the client wants his email without them. Is there a way to exclude fields from the receiver email?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to David, the way he described works. Since Version 9 there is a more convenient way to achieve this:
[TYPO3 - cms-forms - Remove Input from Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72658849/typo3-cms-forms-remove-input-from-email) It uses variants:

```
    variants:
      -
        identifier: hide-1
        renderingOptions:
          enabled: false
        condition: 'stepType == "SummaryPage" || finisherIdentifier in ["EmailToSender", "EmailToReceiver"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Email-Templates are realized in fluid and resided in `sysext/form/Private/Frontend/Templates/Finishers/Email`. There is one template for HTMl-Mails and one for text-mails.

Below I post the important part of the HTML-Template

```
    <f:if condition="{formValue.isMultiValue}">
        <f:then>
            <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <f:for each="{formValue.processedValue}" as="value">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{value}</td>
                    </tr>
                </f:for>
            </table>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><f:format.nl2br>{formValue.processedValue}</f:format.nl2br></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
```

There you can add conditions to exclude special fields.
I don't know how the variable for the field-identifier is named but it could be `name` or `title` or `id`.
Assumed it's `name` then you condition could look like below.

There are two ways you can use, either you allow in a condition all fields that are desired (positive condition):

```
<f:if condition="{formValue.name} == 'street' || {formValue.name} == 'city'">
    ...
</f:if>
```

or you can exclude some fields if its easier (negative condition):

```
<f:if condition="{formValue.name} !== 'zip' && {formValue.name} !== 'country'">
    ...
</f:if>
```

Take care that the connective opperant in the positive condition is `OR / ||` and in the negative condition `AND / &&`.

**IMPORTANT:**
Certainly you know that  you never change the templates directly in any subfolder of sysext but make a copy and change the reference.